# Error when editing products on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, database, sql, product-edit

Getting this error when trying to edit a product on my Magento 2 store.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'webadmin_ex_lega.autosuggest_batch' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `autosuggest_batch` AS `main_table` WHERE (`product_id` = '68') AND (`store_id` = '0')

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using the **Mirasvit** extension **Search AutoComplete & Suggest Pro for Magento 2**.

So check if you have the last version installed and the respective version like Magento 2.0 or 2.1.